# Google Chrome Javascript debugging issue

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

It used to be that when I stopped at a breakpoint in Google Chrome, and hovered over a variable, there would be a popup showing me the value of that variable.  For some reason, that has simply stopped happening.  Can anyone think what might have stopped this behaviour and how I might be able to restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an intermittent problem with Chrome, which is sometimes caused by being in the wrong scope, but not always... sometimes Chrome is just stubborn and doesn't display the tooltip variable evaluations for no obvious reason.  I'd recommend trying to close and open the developer tools, and/or close and open Chrome.  It might get it working.  If that fails, use Firefox.  ;-)

Mine just started working again for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it hangs up and doesn't show tooltip the variable, but this could be fixed with closing/opening debugger.

There may be another reason. You're in one scope, but trying to access variable from another scope.

```
arr.forEach(function(e){ // breakpoint is here
  e.doSeomthing(); // but `e` in inner scope is not defined
});
```

The same for accesing property from outside scope. For latter one may switch on callstack and move to the proper call depth and scope.